# How can I scrape private website using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I try to scrap the next website https://micheque.uy/market but the problem is that required login and password.

[The url that I need to scrap](https://micheque.uy/market)

The problem is that to acces https://micheque.uy/market I need to be logged.

I tried the next code in other URL And I had success but not in this case.

```
`library(rvest)
url <- "https://micheque.uy/market"
pgsession <-html_session(url)

pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]

filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                      "username" = "ibrahimmeljem@gmail.com", 
                      "password" = "*******")

submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
memberlist <- jump_to(pgsession, "https://micheque.uy/market")

page <- read_html(memberlist)

usernames <- html_nodes(x = page, css = "#memberlist .username") 

data_usernames <- html_text(usernames, trim = TRUE) `
```

I have problem with the package RSelenium because this PC is from office, so I must use rvest.

Thanks!